# My contribution pages have gone blank

Tags: joomla, contribution-page

Joomla 3.8.5
CiviCRM 4.7.29
PHP 7.0.7
I have four contribution pages for different membership levels, Bronze, Silver, Gold and Platinum. Everything seemed to be working and I had members signed up through all four pages. At some point, not sure when, three of them stopped working - Bronze, Silver and Platinum. I only found out because potential members emailed me to tell me they couldn't access the pages. I checked from the front end by selecting the appropriate menu items and found that only the Gold went to a contribution page, the other three only produced a blank whit page. I can't find anything in the log that helps.

Comment: If you go to Events > Manage Events > Bronze You should see Event links at the top. Does the live link work right? If so, might just need to put the link back into your menu or the shortcode on the webpage that uses it.

Comment: These are not events, they are membership levels. I don't even have Civi Event installed. (although I might if it had a decent events calendar)

Comment: I have tried adding a new contribution page using the instructions in the CiviCRM documentation for the simplest contribution page possible. Still blank.

Comment: Sorry about that, Have you tested the links for those contribution pages? go to Contributions > Manage Contribution Pages > Bronze and to the right you should see several options, one being Links. Does the Live Page link open a page with content?

Comment: Ok, I now have five contribution pages with slightly different histories: "Gold" - created from scratch, works on Joomla menu link, CiviCRM live page and test drive links. "Bronze", "Silver", "Platinum" and "AG" - copied from "Gold" and edited, blank on all link methods. "Test Contribution" - created from scratch, works from CiviCRM live page and test drive links, blank when called from Joomla menu.

Comment: Correction, "Test Contribution" works from the Joomla menu link. I think I had the wrong contribution page set for that item. So, is it possible that copying a contribution page is what is preventing it from being called properly from a Joomla menu?

Comment: I'd agree that your assessment that coping the Contribution page is the issue. I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks, @IowaBoy. Here's my situation, now. I have disabled and renamed all the non-functional contribution pages. I have recreated the Bronze, Silver and Platinum pages from scratch, copying only text fields where needed. All of them now work fine. I'll addres my thoughts on the source of the problem in my next post. I'll post it as a reply rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is where I am after some head scratching and some inspiration from @IowaBoy. All of my contribution pages are now working, having recreated the problem ones from scratch instead of copying a working one. All of the contribution pages that had problems were created about a year ago and they were working as we had membership sign-ups from all of them. I now think that they stopped working after my upgrade from CiviCRM 4.7.27 to 4.7.29. I suspect this as that I started receiving notifications about the problem some time after the upgrade.

In my investigation of the problem, I verified that a new test contribution page made by copying the working one also did not work. I further verified that a new test contribution page made from scratch worked as expected. I have recreated our non-working contribution pages from scratch and so far they seem to be working. I stronly suspect that something in the 4.7.29 release has broken the process of creating a contribution page by copying. Thanks to IowaBoy for stimulating my thinking process.

Comment: to test this hypothesis on latest I went to http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute?reset=1, checked id=1 was working, then 'made a copy' of it, then went to the live page for id=4 (the clone) and it worked - so if it was a glitch in the code it has been fixed by looks of it.

Comment: What CiviCRM version is that on?

Answer (score 2):

Can I make a suggestion, as i had a similar issue and it showed up after the upgrade.
I had to modify the user.ini from PHP to give more resources, and voila! It mas magic everything came back.
I bumped up a few things while I was at it:
max_execution_time is now at 90
max_input_time doubled it to 180
I think the max_execution_time was it, and civi just needs more time in the newer versions. We're at now 5.11.0 on joomla, and just love it. Been using it for a few years now.